# I want to have this code not be so long and to not be so time consuming to write

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to continue developing on this code but it takes so much time to write. Any ideas on how to make it easier? I mean easier by having it take less time to write.

```
    <div id="jesus">

</div>
<script>var a = ["The","an","a"]
var b = ["deranged","squishy","original","excellent","extraordinary","big nosed","big bird lookin","angry"]
var c = ["cat","shrimp","silas","lobster","isaac","atticus","molly","jorge","POLYNOMIAL"]
var verb = ["flew","jumped","died","boinged"]
var con = ["and","but","or"]
var prep = ["over","on","off","under"]
var op = ["bridge","house","octopus","swing","boat"]
var at = ["The","an","a"]
var rana = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0;
var ranb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 0;
var ranc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 0;
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0;
var ranverb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0;
var rancon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0;
var ranprep = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0;
var ranop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;
var ranat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0;
var tobea = 0;
var tobeb = 0;
var tobec = 0;
var tobed = 0;
var tobee = 0;
var tobeverb = 0;
var tobecon = 0;
var tobeprep = 0;
var tobeop = 0;
var tobeat =0;
if(rana === 0) {tobea = a[0]
}else if(rana === 1) {tobea = a[1]
}else if(rana === 2) {tobea = a[2]}
if(ranb === 0) {tobeb = b[0]
}else if(ranb === 1) {tobeb = b[1]
}else if(ranb === 2) {tobeb = b[2]}
else if(ranb === 3) {tobeb = b[3]}
else if(ranb === 4) {tobeb = b[4]}
else if(ranb === 5) {tobeb = b[5]}
else if(ranb === 6) {tobeb = b[6]}
else if(ranb === 7) {tobeb = b[7]}
if(ranc === 0) {tobec = c[0]
}else if(ranc === 1) {tobec = c[1]
}else if(ranc === 2) {tobec = c[2]}
else if(ranc === 3) {tobec = c[3]}
else if(ranc === 4) {tobec = c[4]}
else if(ranc === 5) {tobec = c[5]}
else if(ranc === 6) {tobec = c[6]}
else if(ranc === 7) {tobec = c[7]}
else if(ranc === 8) {tobec = c[8]}
if(rand === 0) {tobed = a[0]} 
else if(rand === 1) {tobed = a[1]}
if(rand === 0) {tobee = a[0]}
else if(rand === 1) {tobee = a[2]}
if(ranverb === 0) {tobeverb = verb[0]
}else if(ranverb === 1) {tobeverb = verb[1]
}else if(ranverb === 2) {tobeverb = verb[2]}
else if(ranverb === 3) {tobeverb = verb[3]}
if(rancon === 0) {tobecon = con[0]
}else if(rancon === 1) {tobecon = con[1]
}else if(rancon === 2) {tobecon = con[2]}
if(ranprep === 0) {tobeprep = prep[0]
}else if(ranprep === 1) {tobeprep = prep[1]
}else if(ranprep === 2) {tobeprep = prep[2]}
else if(ranprep === 3) {tobeprep = prep[3]}
if(ranop === 0) {tobeop = op[0]
}else if(ranop === 1) {tobeop = op[1]
}else if(ranop === 2) {tobeop = op[2]}
else if(ranop === 3) {tobeop = op[3]}
else if(ranop === 4) {tobeop = op[4]}
if(ranat === 0) {tobeat = at[0]
}else if(ranat === 1) {tobeat = at[1]
}else if(ranat === 2) {tobeat = at[2]}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "a") {tobea = tobed}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "e") {tobea = tobed}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "i") {tobea = tobed}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "o") {tobea = tobed}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "u") {tobea = tobed}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "b") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "c") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "d") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "f") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "g") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "h") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "j") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "k") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "l") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "m") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "n") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "p") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "q") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "r") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "s") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "t") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "v") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "w") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "x") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "y") {tobea = tobee}
if(tobeb.charAt(0) === "z") {tobea = tobee}


if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "a") {tobeat = tobed}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "e") {tobeat = tobed}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "i") {tobeat = tobed}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "o") {tobeat = tobed}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "u") {tobeat = tobed}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "b") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "c") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "d") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "f") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "g") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "h") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "j") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "k") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "l") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "m") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "n") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "p") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "q") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "r") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "s") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "t") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "v") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "w") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "x") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "y") {tobeat = tobee}
if(tobeop.charAt(0) === "z") {tobeat = tobee}

var output = tobea + " " + tobeb + " " + tobec + " " + tobeverb + " " + tobeprep + " " + tobeat + " " + tobeop;


document.getElementById("jesus").textContent = output;

document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = reload;
</script>
```

This is all of the code.

Comment: you may want to look at using some String and/or Array methods, like `indexOf` or `includes` to shorten up the `if...charAt` code

Comment: all those `if(ranb === 1) {tobeb = b[1]` etc ... can be shortened to one statement ... `tobeb=b[ranb]` - pretty basic stuff really

Comment: could you help me with that?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: yes, I can help with that ... look at using some String and/or Array methods, like `indexOf` or `includes` to shorten up the `if...charAt` code  ... and; all those `if(ranb === 1) {tobeb = b[1]` etc ... can be shortened to one statement ... `tobeb=b[ranb]`

Answer (score 0):

I always see what my repetition is trying to achieve

1)get random words from array

2)check if something starts with vowel or not

That can be expressed like this

```
const getRandom = (arr) => arr[(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length -1) + 0)] //following your code not sure if this is correct random
const startsWithVowel = (str)=>/^[aeiou]/.test(str)
```

And then your code will shorten to this.

```
var a = ["The","an","a"]
var b = ["deranged","squishy","original","excellent","extraordinary","big nosed","big bird lookin","angry"]
var c = ["cat","shrimp","silas","lobster","isaac","atticus","molly","jorge","POLYNOMIAL"]
var verb = ["flew","jumped","died","boinged"]
var con = ["and","but","or"]
var prep = ["over","on","off","under"]
var op = ["bridge","house","octopus","swing","boat"]
var at = ["The","an","a"]

const getRandom = (arr) => arr[(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length -1) + 0)]
const startsWithVowel = (str)=>/^[aeiou]/.test(str)

let tobea = getRandom(a),
    tobeb = getRandom(b),
    tobec = getRandom(c),
    tobed = a[getRandom([0,1])],//get 'The' or 'a'
    tobee = a[getRandom([0,2])],//get 'The' or 'an'
    tobeverb =getRandom(verb),
    tobecon = getRandom(con),
    tobeprep = getRandom(prep),
    tobeop = getRandom(op),
    tobeat = getRandom(at);

    tobeat = startsWithVowel(tobeop) ? tobed : tobee
    tobeb = startsWithVowel(tobeb) ? tobed: tobee

    var output = tobea + " " + tobeb + " " + tobec + " " + tobeverb + " " + getRandom(prep) + " " + tobeat + " " + getRandom(op);


    document.getElementById("jesus").textContent = output;

    document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = reload;
```

You can see getRandom can be used in different ways as it is very generic. Always write generic functions as much as possible when refactoring.